# How to bypass sudo password for everything inside a script?

Tags: server, 20.04, password, raspberrypi, visudo

I have a [PADD](https://github.com/pi-hole/PADD) setup on my Raspberry Pi 3 running on Ubuntu Server 20.04.

I can successfully bypassed `sudo` password authentication by adding:

```
pihole_display ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

But when I try to limit to `/usr/local/bin/pihole` only, it doesn't work.

I looked at the file itself to see if I need to add another executable to filter out, but I didn't notice anything else.

Question is, is it possible to simply use `padd.sh` file and any commands in that file won't ask for `sudo` password?

Comment: Run the script with `sudo` and remove it from the script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sudo a command in a script without being asked for a password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155791/how-do-i-sudo-a-command-in-a-script-without-being-asked-for-a-password).

Comment: Adding `sudo` worked.  I'll just add that as the answer to my own question.  Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enter password only once in a bash script needing sudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/711580/how-to-enter-password-only-once-in-a-bash-script-needing-sudo)

Answer (score 0):

This was answered in the comments, but I'll copy it here for visibility

Run the script with `sudo`.  So simple, can't believe I overlooked it.